# pyqtSignal and QObject.receivers(..)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I need to check the signal for the presence of the listener, before it is emitted.

```
class Test(QObject):
    test = pyqtSignal(str,dict)
    def run(self):
        if self.receivers(SIGNAL("test(str,dict)"):
           self.test.emit('blablabla',{})`
```

The signal is connected to the slot right and successfully emits signals.
When checking the signature signal, the method `QObject.receivers()` shows that this signal is not connected.
I understood, reason was incorrect signature, I did not find a method, to specify the faithful signature of signal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature for your signal is `"test(QString, PyQt_PyObject)"`.

So obviously, `str` is mapped to `QString` and other native python object types, `dict`, `list`... are mapped to the C++ type `PyQt_PyObject`.

The list of signal signatures can be obtained through the `QMetaObject` associated with your object:

```
test = Test()
metaobject = test.metaObject()
for i in range(metaobject.methodCount()):
    print(metaobject.method(i).signature())
```

Answer (score 9):

In pyqt5 SIGNAL is deprecated. It is replaced with signal attribute of each QObject

if **QObject**.receivers(**QObject**.**signal**) > 0:

```
    print('signal connected')
```

To Check QPushButton signal clicked() is connected to any slot

```
button = QPushButton()
.
.
if button.receivers(button.clicked) > 0:
    .....
```